# How to say one street branches from another?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

My house is located on a side street that branches from a main street. If I wanted to formally write my home address, how should I do it? I'm thinking:

> [Side street name], branching from [main street name]

**Edit:**

I'm going to send this information to US State Department via this web-form:

[image]

Comment: The form does not ask you to specify the main street or side street. It asks you to fill in the name of the actual name of the street on which you live.  It could not be clearer. The second address line is for: Apt. 5 [apartment numbers] or Residence Five, for example.

Comment: I think if you were to include the wording Alan recommends (**off** {Intersecting Street Name} ) in `Address Line 2` you should be OK.

Comment: No, the wording  in Arabic is not **relevant** here at all. It is not used in English. Please do not give the OP misleading information. The form is a very typical form in English. The receiving database will not accept things like Off [x] street.

Comment: @Lambie. There are many insignificant side streets here, that's why we have to mention the  small street together with the main street to facilitate delivery of a letter for example. Perhaps, it's an urban planning issue.

Comment: Are you interested in what I am saying or  not? I must fill in at least 20 forms like this a year. The receiving database will not be programmed to accept addresses written in English with things like: Off X Street. There is probably somewhere in the form or information you are sending where you can tell them that but not in this form.

Comment: @Lambie my concern is that If i drop off the side street, the us state department wouldn't be able to communicate with me because the postman wouldn't be able to deliver the letter.

Comment: Just use `Address Line 2` for this bit of info, and use whatever English words *your local post office* will understand best:  "branching from " : big street name or "off"  big street name, because the US computer is just going to spit out what it finds in Address Line 2.

Comment: BTW, I've seen US web pages recommending that all addresses destined for foreign countries be entered all in UPPER CASE. Not every postal worker in countries using other than the Latin alphabet will recognize lower-case letters, e.g. that "g" is "G" or that d = D, e = E, and so on.

Comment: What Arab-speaking country is this?

Comment: @Lambie, Egypt.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing conventions vary from country to country.  In the US, for example, a *street address* does not usually contain information about so-called "cross-streets", but takes this basic format:

```
{Number} {Street}  {Floor, Apartment, Condo#, etcetera)
{CityName}, {StateAbbreviation} {PostalCode}
```

such as

> 1234 Elm Street Apt 6
>   Albany, NY 12203

You could say that your street *intersects* a particular street.

Comment: @Lambie actually I mean to send my address to US State Department. In Arabic, the idea of *X branching from Y* is a standard addressing format. I wanted to know if *branching from* would sound familiar, or if not, the best alternative.

Comment: I really don't know. Your local US consulate is probably the best place to ask. You want to make sure your address is in a format that  can be entered properly into the State Department database so that when it is printed out on an envelope it will be in the proper format for the envelope to be delivered to your house.

Comment: @Lambie, please see my post edit

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, I think I should. I just wanted to know if *branching from* would make sense to a native speaker of English.

Comment: I think your question should be "Will the address generated by the US State Department computer make sense to my local postal office?" not whether "branching from" would make sense to an American.  US personnel will probably enter into the database whatever you put on the form.  Enter the address so that return mail will reach you.  The envelope printing algorithm won't be nuanced, I imagine.

Comment: Yes, and then it will no longer be an ELL question, will it?

Answer (score 1):

The usual phrasing is "off [main street]" (see [definition 1b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off), MW). In speech you will often hear "off of", though there's [some](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off_of) [debate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20of) over whether this is valid usage.

Tᴚoɯɐuo is correct, though, that if you want to actually write down your address rather than just describe its location, you would follow the [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_(geography)) for the relevant area.